# Ruby Spawn inherits file handles

Tags: ruby, file, file-descriptor, spawn

I've installed the excellent handle.exe from Mark Rusinovitch which allows to display currently opened file descriptors.

In ruby, when I launch that:

```
require 'tempfile'
file=Tempfile.new('foxylady')
pid=Process::spawn('calc.exe',:close_others=>true)
Process::detach(pid)
file.close
puts(`handle foxylady`)
```

I get that:

```
E:\WORK\voillequinj_maci>ruby a.rb

Handle v3.51
Copyright (C) 1997-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

calc.exe           pid: 4176   type: File           164: C:\Users\VOILLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\foxylady20140702-5908-1sn8edi
```

This makes me think that `Process::spawn` does not do what it should.
`calc.exe` inherits handle opened with `file=Tempfile.new('foxy lady')`.
Am I wrong? Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the FDs, see [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Process.html#method-c-spawn).

```
Process.spawn(command, in: :close, out: :close, err: :close, close_others: true)
```